# Executing shell command in groovy throws 'unexpected char' error

Tags: shell, groovy

I am trying to execute a shell command n groovy

```
def shellString = "s/\[\|]\|\s\|'\|(\|)//g"
def temp2 = "echo response| sed -e ${shellString}".execute()
```

It throws compilation error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 33: unexpected char: '\' @ line 33, column 24.
     def shellString = "s/\[\|]\|\s\|'\|(\|)//g"
                          ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:120)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:132)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.addError(SourceUnit.java:350)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:139)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:234)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:168)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:943)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:605)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:131)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:125)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:560)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:521)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:330)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
```

`shellString` isn't a slashed string, so not sure why a `\` would create a problem. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to escape slash to avoid compilation errors:

```groovy
def shellString = "s/\\[\\|]\\|\\s\\|'\\|(\\|)//g"
def temp2 = "echo response| sed -e ${shellString}".execute()

println temp2.text
```

Output:

```
response| sed -e s/\[\|]\|\s\|'\|(\|)//g
```

Answer (score 4):

This will fail on many levels.  The biggest problem you will face is the fact, that `execute` is really just executing a process (not a shell command).  So first of all you can not use `|` at all.  Next quoting arguments will not work, because `execute` will just split at whitespace.  So if you want to use "shellisms" use the equivalent of `sh -c "..."` instead and use `execute` on a string array.  E.g.

```
["sh", "-c", "..."].execute()
```

Then you can put your `...` shell code in there with all the redirections, quotings, env-vars etc. with the proper Groovy quoting applied as mentioned in the other answer.

And to circumvent all of that: why even bother with `sed` here?  Just use `replaceAll` on the resulting string on the groovy side of things.